# Algorithm to count occurance in a consecutive amount of time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl, sorting, count

I have a set of data that that tells me the on/off status of a component as a function of time. The data looks like this :

```
0    1
120  1
240  0
360  0
480  1
600  1
720  1
840  0
960  0
1080  0
1200  1
1320  1
1440  0
1560  0
1680  1
1800  0
1920  1
```

First column shows the time in second and the second column shows the status (1 is on, 0 is off).

I need to know the what is the 600 seconds with the most 1 in it. For example, 0-600 has 3*120 s so 360 seconds where component is on. But 120-720 has 4 etc... This means that this is not only 0-600, 600-1200, it can by any 600 seconds. The hard thing is that this is a cycle, meaning that the worst hour could be from 1920 to 480 (Note that this cycle has 2040s meaning time 2040 is also time 0). The time steps are not always equal. In this case it is a constant 120s, but it could be a mix of 120s and 150s for example.

The only thing I can think of is to scan the file from 0-600, check time is was on, 120-720, 240-840 etc... but it is very time consuming. Especially since I can have very big files.

The program is in Perl, but I only need the algorithm (if it exists). Do any of you has an idea on what would be the best approach?

Thank you

Comment: With a fixed timestep of 120 seconds, you can scan your file until you find a block with 5 matches, since this is guaranteed to be the maximum. If there are no blocks with 5 matches, you have no choice but to read the entire file. In the case of a tie, if you want to report *all* blocks that have the maximum instead of just the first one, you will also have to read the whole file. Without a fixed timestep, you again have no choice but to read the whole file.

Comment: Please show how the numbers go when you wrap around a cycle. Please also explain what the algorithm is supposed to do when the time gaps change from 120 to 150 - we can't interpolate that `1` as 120/150ths of `1` can we?

Comment: As for the cycle, imagine that after 1920s, you have 2040, but 2040 is also 0s since it is a cycle. For the time steps, You can calculate it. From 0-120 I have a 1 so it's on 120 sec. You can add everything until you've reached a time > 1h.

Comment: You start by asking for the number of on (1) samples in a 600s window but then talk about the total on time for the window. Which do you want? Assuming the latter, how should on time be calculated? e.g. it was on at both 480s and 600s, so presumably it was on for the full 120s in between. It was off 360s and on at 480s: should that count as 0s, 120s, 60s (splitting the difference)? Similarly, it was on at 120s and off at 240s; how should that be counted?

Comment: You state that 0-600 has 3*120, and 120-720 has 4, but if you look at the data, both of those windows of 6 periods contain the same number of 1's. Is there a particular rule for when a period should be counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't quite clear what value you're trying to calculate, but your core problem appears to be finding an algorithm for getting the samples in each sliding 600s window. The sliding window can be implemented as an array. Add new samples to the end and purge old samples to keep the total size <= 600s. The only tricky part is accounting for the time values being modulo 2040.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(pp);

my @window;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($t, $on) = split / +/, $line;

    # add sample to sliding window
    push @window, { t => $t, on => $on};

    # limit window size to 600s
    while (1) {
        last if @window <= 1;

        my $start = $window[0]{t};
        my $stop  = $window[-1]{t};

        # account for time values being mod 2040
        if ($stop < $start) {
            $stop += 2040;
        }

        if ($stop - $start > 600) {
            # purge old sample from window
            shift @window;
        }
        else {
            last;
        }
    }

    # do something with @window
    pp \@window;
}

__DATA__
0    1
120  1
240  0
360  0
480  1
600  1
720  1
840  0
960  0
1080  0
1200  1
1320  1
1440  0
1560  0
1680  1
1800  0
1920  1
0    1
120  1
240  0
360  0
```

The values in `@window` look like this:

```
# no wrapping
[
  { on => 1, t => 0 },
  { on => 1, t => 120 },
  { on => 0, t => 240 },
  { on => 0, t => 360 },
  { on => 1, t => 480 },
  { on => 1, t => 600 },
]

# with wrapping
[
  { on => 0, t => 1560 },
  { on => 1, t => 1680 },
  { on => 0, t => 1800 },
  { on => 1, t => 1920 },
  { on => 1, t => 0 },
  { on => 1, t => 120 },
]
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go. Thanks. From what I understand, it is called a moving average. There is a very clever perl code on that :
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Simple_moving_average

Comment: @Moose1231: It's not really a moving average but the basic idea (looking at a moving subset taken from a large stream of data) is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be solved in the following manner.
Define an integer n; Keep adding the ones to n until a zero occurs. That is, if a zero occurs set n to zero. In the process record the maximum n occurrence and the seconds at that time. To do this define another variable m and let m be the max value. Now if n becomes greater than m then m=n. In this way you can get near the 600s interval containing maximum number of 1s. Good luck. I hope, it worked.

Comment: What if it is on 360s, of 120 sec and on 120sec again. Your manner would give me 360s instead of 480s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that points are sorted by time, you can keep buffer of consecutive points in a way that time difference between first point and last point do not exceed 600. Here is the code in C#:

```
// Class for data point
class Point {
    public int Time { get; private set; }
    public bool On { get; private set; }

    public Point(int time, bool on) {
        Time = time;
        On = on;
    }
}

Point[] points = {
    new Point(0, true),
    new Point(120, true),
    new Point(240, false),
    new Point(360, false),
    new Point(480, true),
    new Point(600, true),
    new Point(720, true),
    new Point(840, false),
    new Point(960, false),
    new Point(1080, false),
    new Point(1200, true),
    new Point(1320, true),
    new Point(1440, false),
    new Point(1560, false),
    new Point(1680, true),
    new Point(1800, false),
    new Point(1920, true),
};

int GetMaxIntervalCount(IEnumerable<Point> points) {
    LinkedList<Point> buff = new LinkedList<Point>();
    int buffCount = 0, res = -1;
    foreach (Point point in points) {
        buff.AddFirst(point);
        while (buff.Count > 0) {
            Point last = buff.Last.Value;
            if (Math.Abs(last.Time - point.Time) > 600) {
                buff.RemoveLast();
                if (last.On) {
                    --buffCount;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (point.On) {
            ++buffCount;
        }
        res = Math.Max(res, buffCount);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Currently it returns only maximum count, but it can be easily adjusted to also keep actual buffer. Time complexity of a method is O(N) (each point will be 
"touched" at most 2 times - on adding and deleting from buffer).

Comment: That's the thing, it might not be consecutive. As I answered to a previous comment :
What if it is on 360s, of 120 sec and on 120sec again. Your manner would give me 360s instead of 480s